# два и более animate одновременный запуск

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

```
$('.chart-item-yellow').animate({
    width:0,
    left:374
});

$('.chart-item-blue').animate({
    width:339,
    left:442
});

$('.chart-item-red').animate({
    width:408,
    left:442
});

$('.chart-item-orange').animate({
    width:179,
    left:442
});
```

Есть несколько animate эффектов, но они выполняются последовательно, можно ли их запустить одновременно?

Comment: Но они же срабатывают одновременно. То есть, есть конечно между итерациями процессора интервалы, Но визуально всё ровно.

Comment: добавьте html и css на котором все проверяете. иначе не видно проблемы